# BallonTip Java, how to move the balloon

Tags: java, balloon-tip

I'm using [BalloonTip](http://timmolderez.be/balloontip/doku.php?id=balloontip:createpositioner) component in my program and I couldn't find the answer how to move it (to the right).

```
PoleTekstowe = new javax.swing.JTextField();

Balonik = new BalloonTip(PoleTekstowe, "Nie dzielimy przez 0!");
Balonik.setVisible(false);
Balonik.setCloseButton(BalloonTip.getDefaultCloseButton(), false);
```

[image: Too bad I cant post an image yet.]

Comment: Can you also link to the BallonTip library

Comment: http://timmolderez.be/balloontip/doku.php?id=balloontip:createpositioner  Full documentation is within the download... heres picture of program http://imageshack.com/a/img537/6278/LNTBis.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like...

```
BalloonTip tip = new BalloonTip(
                field, 
                new JLabel("Type Something"),
                new RoundedBalloonStyle(5,5,Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK), 
                BalloonTip.Orientation.RIGHT_BELOW, 
                BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED, 
                15, 
                15, 
                true);
```

Which is demonstrated in the [Tweaking a balloon tip's position](http://timmolderez.be/balloontip/doku.php?id=balloontip:usingballoontip#tweaking_a_balloon_tip_s_position) section of the manual...

[image]

I'd also grab a copy of the source code, as it makes it eaiser to see how they build the tooltips...

Comment: Thanks for help, however I get the message that this type of constructor is undefined. ?? The constructor BalloonTip(JTextField, String, RoundedBalloonStyle, BalloonTip.Orientation, BalloonTip.AttachLocation, int, int, boolean) is undefined

Comment: What version are you using?  I downloaded [1.2.4.1](https://java.net/projects/balloontip/downloads)

Comment: I also use the latest version

Comment: Well, I used the code above to produce the screen shot. Make sure you've imported all the required classes

Comment: Ohhhh, Im sorry, I was writing a String into Second field and it should be JLabel as you post it..... Sorry, and thanks it works!
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/1142/zxlBVv.jpg